# Difference between layout-finger and layout directory

Tags: android

In android, there are different sub-directory under 'res'

- layout
- layout-finger
- layout-land-finger

Can somebody please explain what are the difference between these directories?

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

The official explanation is in the [SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#AlternateResources). Assuming that these three are the only layout resource directories:

- Layouts in `res/layout-land-finger/` will be used if the device has a finger-friendly touchscreen (i.e., capacitive, versus a resistive touchscreen or no touchscreen) and is being held in landscape orientation.
- Layouts in `res/layout-finger/` will be used if the device has a finger-friendly touchscreen and is not being held in landscape orientation.
- Layouts in `res/layout/` will be used if the device has a resistive or no touchscreen